# Not able to see the items in the cart using "redux toolkit"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I was making small project of react in which I wanted to use "Redux toolkit" for my cart logic.

What I want :

When I will click on button "Add To Bag", it should add ( quantity, color, name, company name etc ) into cart as a 1 item.

And when I will open a Cart page, it should render it.

Here is my Redux code :

Index.js

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./Redux/Store";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </>
);
```

Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "./Slices/CartSlices";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cart1: cartReducer,
  },
});
```

CartSlices.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Cart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});
export const { addItem } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

SingleProduct.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./SingleProduct.css";
import { addItem } from "../Redux/Slices/CartSlices";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function SingleProduct() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const productData = location.state?.data;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [selectedColorIndex, setSelectedColorIndex] = useState(null);
  const [selectedQuantity, setSelectedQuantity] = useState(0);

  const QuantitySelect = () => {
    const options = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => (
      <option key={i} value={i}>
        {i}
      </option>
    ));
    return options;
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <img
            src={productData.attributes.image}
            alt=""
            className="mt-5 rounded-5 ms-5 shadow"
            style={{
              objectFit: "cover",
              height: "400px",
              width: "550px",
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6 mt-5">
          <h2 className="fw-bold">{productData.attributes.title}</h2>
          <h5 className="fw-bold text-black-50 mt-3">
            {productData.attributes.company}
          </h5>
          <p className="mt-3">
            <span>$</span>
            {productData.attributes.price}
          </p>
          <p className="lead fs-6 fw-light lh-lg">
            {productData.attributes.description}
          </p>
          <div>
            <p className="fw-bold"> Colors</p>
            <div className="d-flex">
              {productData.attributes.colors.map((color, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className={`dot ${
                    selectedColorIndex === index ? "selected-dot" : ""
                  }`}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
                  onClick={() => setSelectedColorIndex(index)}
                ></div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div>
              <p className="mt-3 fw-bold">Quantity</p>
              <select
                className="form-select w-50 rounded-3"
                value={selectedQuantity}
                onChange={(e) => setSelectedQuantity(e.target.value)}
              >
                <QuantitySelect />
              </select>
            </div>

             {/* <Link to={"/cart"}> */}
              <div
                className="btn mt-4 text-white"
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#463aa1", height: "40px" }}
                onClick={(e) =>
                  dispatch(
                    addItem({
                      image: productData.attributes.image,
                      companyName: productData.attributes.company,
                      price: productData.attributes.price,
                      title: productData.attributes.title,
                      color: selectedColorIndex,
                      quantity: selectedQuantity,
                    })
                  )
                }
              >
                Add To Bag
              </div>
          {/* </Link> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Empty div for space */}
      <div style={{ height: "50px" }}></div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default SingleProduct;
```

Cart.js

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
function Cart() {
  const items = useSelector((state) => state);

  console.log("Items : ", items);
  // render code
}
```

I tried to debug through "Redux dev tool" extension. I found 2 items in the cart. ( which is correct behaviour )

[image]

But when I try to print on console ( in cart.js , I tried to print ), I can not see 2 items in the cart.

[image]

Where I am making a mistake ?

Observation :

> If I redirected to the "/cart" page immediately after clicking the
> "Add to Bag" button, ( using Link tag ) then I can see element in the
> cart.
> But if I redirected to "/cart" page separately, then
> above problem appears.

Update :
App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  About,
  Cart,
  Checkout,
  Error,
  HomeLayout,
  Landing,
  Login,
  Orders,
  Products,
  Register,
  SingleProduct,
} from "./pages";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomeLayout />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Landing />,
      },
      {
        path: "products",
        element: <Products />,
      },
      {
        path: "products/:id",
        element: <SingleProduct />,
      },
      {
        path: "cart",
        element: <Cart />,
      },
      {
        path: "about",
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: "checkout",
        element: <Checkout />,
      },
      {
        path: "orders",
        element: <Orders />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    element: <Register />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
]);
function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Another Update :
Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BsSunFill, BsMoonFill, BsCart3 } from "react-icons/bs";
import { FaBarsStaggered } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavLinks } from "./NavLinks";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Navbar() {
  const items = useSelector((state) => state);
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-clr">
      <div className="container">
        <NavLink
          to="/"
          className=" navbar-brand btn btn-sm fs-6 d-none d-md-block text-white fs-6"
          style={{ background: "#016efe" }}
        >
          C
        </NavLink>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <FaBarsStaggered className="text-white" />
          </span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto ">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="nav-link active text-black  mx-3"
                aria-current="page"
                href="/"
              >
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-black mx-3" href="about">
                About
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-black mx-3" href="product">
                Product
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="nav-link text-black mx-3 "
                // style={{ background: "#02152c" }}
                href="/cart"
              >
                Cart
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-black mx-3" href="checkout">
                Checkout
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-black mx-3" href="orders">
                Orders
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {/* <NavLinks /> */}
        </div>

        <NavLink to="/cart" class="position-relative">
          <div>
            <BsCart3
              style={{ height: "30px", width: "30px" }}
              className="text-black"
            />
            <span
              class="position-absolute top-5 start-90 translate-middle badge rounded-pill"
              style={{ background: "#016efe" }}
            >
              {items.cart1.length}
            </span>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: It seems there is *some* navigation action involved here. Can you [edit] to clarify how exactly you get from rendering `SingleProduct` to rendering `Cart`, the exact reproduction steps, and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: @DrewReese I am not going from `SingleProduct` to `cart`.  Once booked, I am staying on the `SingleProduct`.  But while debugging issue, I changed behaviour,   and after booking I redircted to `Cart` using `Link to={/cart} ` ( wrap button div inside this tag ) and found that I am getting items of the cart.

Comment: @DrewReese 1 more observation :  I have other pages also ( like About ) So If I booked product from `SingleProduct` page, and redirected directly to `Cart` page. I can see item in cart. But then if I visited `About` page, and then again booked another product from `SingleProduct` and directed to `Cart` page but here I can see only latest booked product.  Previously booked product is not there.

Comment: @DrewReese : I have updated `SingleProduct` and `Routing` code. Please find it in main question.

Comment: So you say when `SingleProduct` renders the `Link` that wraps the `div` element that when clicked dispatches the `addItem` action that the item is correctly added to the store, and `Cart` is rendered and you can see the correct state selected from the store? Ok, so in this *other* scenario that you say isn't working... *what* are the exact reproduction steps and code used? See [mcve]. At this point I'm still guess that you are either manually updating the URL in the address bar or using some other non-React-Router mechanism to navigate around the app which is reloading the page.

Comment: @DrewReese It is working perfectly but as you guessed it is refreshing page when I click on `Cart` ( through navbar ) And after refreshing, cart item is becoming zero. Without refreshing if I am able to redirect to `Cart` ( through `Link` ) then I can see `items`.  So in a nutshell , what I want to say, through above code, if I booked an item and if I open `Redux Dev tool` extension then I can see items in the cart.  ( I have added its screen shot ). But if I go to `cart` page, then it is getting refreshed and item is becoming zero.

Comment: Can you share the navigation code, the navbar?

Comment: @DrewReese       I have update code of `navbar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257227/discussion-between-user1745866-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Navbar` component is rendering raw anchor tags that when clicked will result in the page being reloaded and all state, including the Redux store, being reset when the page reloads and the app remounts.

Instead of raw anchor tags use either the `Link` or `NavLink` component(s) from `react-router-dom`.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BsSunFill, BsMoonFill, BsCart3 } from "react-icons/bs";
import { FaBarsStaggered } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavLinks } from "./NavLinks";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Navbar() {
  const items = useSelector((state) => state);
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-clr">
      <div className="container">
        <NavLink
          to="/"
          className=" navbar-brand btn btn-sm fs-6 d-none d-md-block text-white fs-6"
          style={{ background: "#016efe" }}
        >
          C
        </NavLink>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
            <FaBarsStaggered className="text-white" />
          </span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto ">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link active text-black  mx-3"
                aria-current="page"
                to="/"
              >
                Home
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link text-black mx-3" to="/about">
                About
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link text-black mx-3" to="/product">
                Product
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link text-black mx-3 "
                // style={{ background: "#02152c" }}
                to="/cart"
              >
                Cart
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link text-black mx-3" to="/checkout">
                Checkout
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link text-black mx-3" to="/orders">
                Orders
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <NavLink to="/cart" class="position-relative">
          <div>
            <BsCart3
              style={{ height: "30px", width: "30px" }}
              className="text-black"
            />
            <span
              class="position-absolute top-5 start-90 translate-middle badge rounded-pill"
              style={{ background: "#016efe" }}
            >
              {items.cart1.length}
            </span>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are redirecting to your cart page with a refresh then you should use [redux-persist](https://blog.logrocket.com/persist-state-redux-persist-redux-toolkit-react/) to store that data in the user's local machine, and if you are not getting data while console.logging, try adding this line in your `cartSlice.js`

```
export const cartSelector = state => state.Cart;
```

and secondly, change **cart1 to Cart** in `Store.js`. Always keep the same name in your store.js and slicename like Cart and Cart, not Cart and Cart1.

import your `cartSelector` in Cart.js;

```
let cartItem = useSelector(cartSelector);
```

I hope it will help you.